# While using "pip install --no-index --find-links=", I was prompted with an error "you must give at least one requirement to install"

Tags: python, pip

As titled. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: in order for us to help you, you need to provide additional information on your question ... logs or output will be a good way to start

Comment: You've written a command that attempts to install nothing. Why did you do that? What were you attempting to achieve?

Comment: @Book Of Zeus, it was the error message that I received.

Comment: @user2357112, I received this error for just about any package installation.

Comment: @user2357112, e.g. >> pip install --no-index --find-links=C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/package-folder

Comment: @CKWong: That's still a command that attempts to install *nothing*. You haven't told pip to install anything. Is there something you want to install?

Comment: @user2357112: I want to install pyautogui (and some other packages) on my work laptop for some projects, but I am having a hard time installing them. Basically all the other options that involve checking pypi online for dependencies will not work. Using this --no-index --find-links is the only option that I have.

Comment: @CKWong: But you're not telling pip to install pyautogui. You're just telling it to install. pip is asking you, install what? Put the pyautogui part back in.

Comment: In case you have some requirement file, you should use: pip install -r requirements_training.txt, anyway see https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/

Comment: Give more details on your question. Show that you have done some research and not able to resolve even if you found a solution

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --no-index --find-links . "C:\Temp\blahblah.whl"
```

can be used instead as you must give at least one requirement.